# Azure Resource Template: language expression is not supported

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I'm creating an Azure resource template and getting this validation error when I specify tags:

> New-AzureResourceGroupDeployment : Error 1: Code=InvalidTemplate;
>   Message=Deployment template validation failed: 'The template  resource
>   'hosting-plan' at line '86' and column '10' is not valid: Template
>   language expression  '[parameters('intranetConnectivity')]' is not
>   supported..'.

Here's the relevant section of the template:

```
"parameters": {
    "intranetConnectivity": {
        "type": "bool",
        "defaultValue": false
    },
    ...
}

"name": "[parameters('siteName')]",
"type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
"location": "[parameters('siteLocation')]",
"tags": {
    "[concat('hidden-related:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]": "Resource",
    "ServiceModel": "[parameters('serviceModel')]",
    "IntranetConnectivity": "[parameters('intranetConnectivity')]",
    "Environment": "[parameters('environment')]"
},
```

I thought maybe the parameter name was too long, but I get the same error regardless of the parameter name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that it didn't like me using a boolean parameter in a string value.  I changed the parameter definition to string and everything works.

```
"intranetConnectivity": {
    "type": "string",
       "allowedValues": [
           "true",
           "false"
       ],
    "defaultValue": "false"
},
```

Comment: This is obviously quite a few years old now, but a different approach if you were unwilling to change the type on intranetConnectivity from bool to string, due to other dependencies, could have been to use an [if statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-logical#if) to assign the Tag value.

That would have looked something like:
```"IntranetConnectivity": "[if(parameters('intranetConnectivity'), 'true', 'false')]```

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify Tags only support string values, not anything else. [Check the limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-using-tags)

- > Not all resource types support tags. To determine if you can apply a tag to a resource type, see Tag support for Azure resources.
- > Each resource or resource group can have a maximum of 50 tag
  >   name/value pairs. If you need to apply more tags than the maximum
  >   allowed number, use a JSON string for the tag value. The JSON string
  >   can contain many values that are applied to a single tag name. A
  >   resource group can contain many resources that each have 50 tag
  >   name/value pairs.
- > The tag name is limited to 512 characters, and the tag value is
  >   limited to 256 characters. For storage accounts, the tag name is
  >   limited to 128 characters, and the tag value is limited to 256
  >   characters.
- > Generalized VMs don't support tags.
- > Tags applied to the resource group are not inherited by the resources
  >   in that resource group.
- > Tags can't be applied to classic resources such as Cloud Services.
- > Tag names can't contain these characters: <, >, %, &, \, ?, /